# How to add a drip edge to a steel deck beam over a porch

Tags: roof, deck, waterproofing, porch

So I have rust and water damage from water rolling down from the curved porch beam into a porch ceiling.  I don't have the same problem with my top-floor porch since that has a roof above it.  The beam has rounded edges so it makes it especially easy for the water to roll around that corner into the ceiling.

My question: is there an easy and cheap way to add some sort of drip edge to this beam that's not too unsightly.   If there is a product made for this, even better since it would be ready-made.  I noticed that there is some automotive stick on drip edge that maybe I can add, but I wonder if there is an even better more appropriate way.  For instance, I've noticed if you put a string on an edge, even that can be enough sometimes to attract the drip flow of water.

Should I instead focus on adding a drip edge to the tile floor above the beam?  If so it would it have to be a significant overhang to protect the entire beam, as any water that still lands on the beam will roll into the ceiling below?  I only want to stop the water from rolling into the ceiling.  I don't mind if the water drips down and puddles below the beam.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You've had _so_ many issues with this place! But, I'm certain it's going to be fantastic when you're done fixing it all up. Keep at it! Your last question before you're done should be worded in a way that you can use it as an excuse to dump a ton of before/after pics for us to admire your work. :D

Comment: @FreeMan thanks for all the comments.  New homeowner trying to fix up all the issues.  I have some after pictures of the joist work which I'll post soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a run of magnetic weatherstripping:

[image]

<sub>[Source](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.grainger.com%2Fproduct%2FPEMKO-Door-Frame-Weatherstrip-3EHA1&psig=AOvVaw33-Os_NLbI5G9gWOOGokfv&ust=1621082419824000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CA0QjhxqFwoTCPiaveOYyfACFQAAAAAdAAAAABAa)</sub>

You could back it with thin double-stick tape for an even more secure hold. Prep the metal a bit so it's smooth and clean.

Answer (score 0):

Your porch deck seems a typical concrete on the metal deck slab, however, the odd thing is it looks like (from the photo) a metal panel was attached to make the smooth look of the ceiling, and it has started to rust out and separated from the slab.

If this is the case, depends on the ownership of the building/unit, you have two options:

- Contact the landlord or the building management as they are the responsible parties for the look of the building facade, and the safety of occupants.
- Call a contractor to perform the necessary and proper repair.

I would against any cosmetic fix that hides the root problem for temporary good looks.

Comment: I'm the owner so should be easy - a metal mesh with stucco was added and the water was dripping around the curve of the frame and sliding into the stucco  filling it with water and rusting it out.

Comment: Wish you are correct. Good luck.